# Json to Chart using highchart export server with Node js module its throw error

Tags: node.js, highcharts

Previously it was working with highcart-export.js but after upgrading it is throwing the below error.

[image]

Comment: Could you provide options of the chart that you want to export along with the used method of exporting (through a CLI or by running a node module)?

Comment: Can you please ellobrate more? I don't understand what you are saying.

Comment: I mean could you provide chart options (a JSON file) and the method that you use to export to an image (do you use commands through console or do you run some node module). Here is more info about available methods of exporting: https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server.

Comment: @pawel_d I am using node module.

Comment: @pawel_d I changed in JSON file directly it is working but I generating from code side so is there any other way to pass this function.

Comment: In case you generate a chart through a node module, you can use the argument called customCode. More info can be found here: https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server.

Comment: @pawel_d Can you please guide how can i write the formatter code in this function?

Comment: I believe that this topic: https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=44120 was created by you too, right? I have left there an answer for your question along with the modified code.

Answer (score 0):

Just need to pass label formatter in legend. After adding `labelFormatter` my issue was resolved.

```
"legend": {
"labelFormatter": function () {
     return this.name + ' (click to hide)';
},
```